# Can't setup two-way binding of component with model on Vue.js(latest 3.4.21)

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

I'm trying to learn `vue.js`. But code from official documentation not working. And I can't find why. Vue tells that `Property "PROPERTY_NAME" was accessed during render but is not defined on instance.`
But this property defined in `props` of component, like in manual. I found, that from version 3.4 I should use `defineModel` and SFC, but for now it's just a kind of complicated. I want simple way and in one `index.html` file for now, without export, one file - one component etc.

The code is:

```
<div id="app">
    <test-component v-model:first-name="firstName" v-model:last-name="lastName"></test-component>
</div>

<script>
Vue.createApp({
    components: {
            'test-component' : {
            props: {
                firstName: String,
                lastName: String
                },
            emits: [ 'update:firstName', 'update:lastName'],
            template: `
                <input type="text" :value="firstName" @input="$emit('update:firstName', $event.target.value)"/>
                <input type="text" :value="lastName" @input="$emit('update:lastName', $event.target.value)"/>
                `
            }
        }
    }).mount('#app');
```

Comment: The problem is you use `firstName` and `lastName` inside the template of app (which is in itself a component) but they are not declared into app. They're only declared inside `<test-component>` which expects them as props from app (which does not have them). Without them being declared into the upper component `update:whatever` doesn't update anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't initializing **firstName** and **lastName** anywhere, so essentially the value is not being written at all.
Add this code before the "components" property.

```
...

data(): {
  firstName: '',
  lastName: '',
}, 

...
```

Comment: Yep. It's working. But can't see logic in it. In fact I declade one variable twice. Once for init and second for a "input stream"

Comment: @DuhVir You're declaring it once in the parent component and then passing the variables to be modified in the child. 
You may find the new composition API a better fit for you - https://vuejs.org/guide/extras/composition-api-faq.html

Comment: yes. after some research I fugured out why variables declared twice. The name of variables get things unclear. In props we just describe component itself, and when we use component than we use "other" variable, from application, it can be array value etc. In manual there was similar names and it confused me. Now I understood for what reason it done this way. Composition API will be in next lessons, now just basics )